# Как получить элементы из списка?

Tags: c#, list

Есть метод переопределения, который вытаскивает последние n-элементов списка. Допустим списке у меня 10 элементов, а хочу я получить 100 элементов. Как заполнить эти 90 элементов нулями?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int takeCount)
{
    if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
    if (takeCount < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("takeCount", "must not be negative"); }
    if (takeCount == 0) { yield break; }

    T[] result = new T[takeCount];
    int i = 0;

    int sourceCount = 0;
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        result[i] = element;
        i = (i + 1) % takeCount;
        sourceCount++;
    }

    if (sourceCount < takeCount)
    {
        takeCount = sourceCount;
        i = 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < takeCount; ++j)
    {
        yield return result[(i + j) % takeCount];
    }
}
```

Comment: А `0` это валидное значение для типа `T`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP эмм. а что это значит)

Comment: Ну у вас же метод обобщенный? Я намекаю вам, что 0 не может быть значением любого типа T. Например `new[] { "a", "b", "c" }.TakeLast(10)` что должно вернуть?

Comment: По идее, правильно было бы заполнить недостающие элементы через default(T). Он либо NULL'ы проставит, либо 0.

Comment: ну тогда "0" @АндрейNOP

Comment: @AxixaTimano, а для List<DataTable> ?

Comment: Ок, а если коллекция экземпляров `Person`?

Comment: Я бы добавил третий необязательный параметр в метод что-то вроде `T def = default(T)`

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы вернуть некоторое количество элементов с конца последовательности, нам нужно перебрать все ее элементы, поэтому считаю приемлемым переписать ваш метод таким образом:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int takeCount)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (takeCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(takeCount), "must not be negative");
    if (takeCount == 0) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return source.Reverse().Take(takeCount).Reverse();
}
```

Ну и, т. к. заведомо `count + takeCount >= takeCount`, можно дополнить исходную последовательность значениями `def` в количестве `takeCount` шт.:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int takeCount, T def = default)
{
    ...
    return source.Reverse().Take(takeCount).Reverse()
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(def, takeCount)).Take(takeCount);
}
```

Еще один вариант, который не будет хранить абсолютно все элементы входной последовательности без необходимости:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int takeCount, T def = default)
{
    ...
    var queue = new Queue<T>(takeCount);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (queue.Count == takeCount) queue.Dequeue();
        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
    return queue.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(def, Math.Max(0, takeCount - queue.Count)));
}
```

Очередь ([`System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs)) использует внутри такой же подход с "циклическим массивом", что и у вас.